# Angular SwUpdate Jest test

Tags: angular, jestjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a PWA and i would like to test, that dialog shown when there are updates reloads the location if user agreed to update.

Here is my test:

```
describe('AppUpdateDialog', () => {
    let component: AppUpdateDialog;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppUpdateDialog>;

    const dialogMock = {
        close: () => {
            // Empty method for testing
        },
    };

    const swUpdateMock = {
        activateUpdate: () => {
            return Promise.resolve();
        },
    };

    beforeEach(async () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppUpdateDialog],
            imports: [
                MatIconModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                MatDialogModule,
                ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
                    enabled: environment.production,
                    registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately',
                }),
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: MatDialogRef,
                    useValue: dialogMock,
                },
                { provide: SwUpdate, useValue: swUpdateMock },
            ],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppUpdateDialog);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should render correctly', () => {
        expect(fixture).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should close the dialog', () => {
        jest.spyOn(component.dialogRef, 'close');
        component.onNoClick();
        expect(component.dialogRef.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should activate update and reload on yes click', async () => {
        const mockReload = jest.fn();
        const mockLocation = { reload: mockReload };
        Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', { value: mockLocation });
        component.onYesClick();
        expect(mockReload).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

So my tests fails on the last line with:

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

How to correctly fix this test case?